# Got an Unhandeled Error at run time while checking state of user

Tags: reactjs, next.js, aws-amplify-cli

```js
import { withAuthenticator, AmplifySignOut } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react'
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function Profile() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    checkUser()
  }, [])
  async function checkUser() {
    const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
    setUser(user);   //<=Error Occured at
  }
  if (!user) return null
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-semibold tracking-wide mt-6">Profile</h1>
      <h3 className="font-medium text-gray-500 my-2">Username: {user.username}</h3>
      <p className="text-sm text-gray-500 mb-6">Email: {user.attributes.email}</p>
      <AmplifySignOut />
    
    </>
  )
}

export default withAuthenticator(Profile)
```

```
Error:::
Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Profile`.
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was related with `<AmplifySignOut />` component, it seems that component does not exists in current library version, so what I did was just get the signOut callback from props and using a custom button to call this action.

```
// pages/profile.js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'
import { withAuthenticator,   } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react'

function Profile({signOut}) { // <-- !!!         Here
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    // Access the user session on the client
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then(user => {
        console.log("User: ", user)
        setUser(user)
      })
      .catch(err => setUser(null))
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      { user &&  <div> 
          <h1>Welcome, {user.username}</h1>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>// <-- Here
          </div> }
    </div>
  )
}

export default withAuthenticator(Profile)
```

Please check the most updated version of documentation because implmentation migth have changed over time
[Amplify Docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js/#sign-up)